# form inputs data failed to be received when element is inserted with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I am trying to dynamically change the html of parent form element to display according the what the user wants to upload, then retrieve the data from that child element. I saved the list of children to dynamically input in the js folder leaving the parent form element empty.
The issue is:

a) When I dynamically input the preferred child element according to what user wants to upload, It doesn't retrieve the values even though it shows in the DOM that the element is there.

b) Whereas if I statically input the child element in html folder, it works just fine. but when the child is changed again, its still the statically inputted values I get back.
please how do I go about this?? Here's the codepen showing it.

```
 <div class="upload-box container mt-3">
    <div class="title-box-d">
      <h3 class="title-d upload-type">Uploading A Car</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box-collapse-wrap form ">
      <div class="form-group mb-5">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="upload">What Do You Want To Upload?</label>
            <select class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="upload">
              <option value="cars">Car</option>
              <option value="houses">House/Home</option>
              <option value="land">Land Properties</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <form class="form-a form-upload">
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

The JS

```
  ///////////////////////
  /*--/ Project Logic /--*/
  //////////////////////

  const projectData = {
    uploadCategories: {
      carForm: ` <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="file">Add Photo</label>
          <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple"
            class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="location">Location</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="location">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="brand">Car Brand</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="brand"
            placeholder="Eg Toyota, Lexus etc">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="car-model">Car Model</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="car-model"
            placeholder="eg Venza, Sienna, Corolla Etc">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="year">Year</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="year">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="condition">Condition</label>
          <select class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="condition">
            <option>Brand New</option>
            <option>Nigerian Used</option>
            <option>Foreign Used</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="transmission">Transmission</label>
          <select class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="transmission">
            <option>Automatic</option>
            <option>Manual</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="registered">Registered?</label>
          <select class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="registered">
            <option>Yes</option>
            <option>No</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="mileage">Mileage</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="mileage"
            placeholder="Mileage (km)">

          <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <label for="price">Price</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="price">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Description</label>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a"
            placeholder="Add more description to your Ad" id="description" cols="30" rows="30"
            style="height: 10rem;"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-b">Upload</button>
      </div>
    </div>`,
      houseForm: `<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="file">Add Photo</label>
          <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple"
            class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="location">Location</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="location">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="title"
            placeholder="Title or name of the Property">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="area">Property Size (sqm)</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="area">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="bedrooms">Bedrooms</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="bedrooms">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="bathrooms">Bathrooms</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="bathrooms">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sale-status">For Sale Or rent?</label>
          <select class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="sale-status">
            <option>For Sale</option>
            <option>For Rent</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="garage">Garage</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="garage">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="price">Price</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="price">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="amenities">Other Amenities</label>
          <select class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="amenities" multiple style="height: 10rem;">
            <option>Parking Space</option>
            <option>24 Hours Electricity</option>
            <option>Internet</option>
            <option>Air Conditioning</option>
            <option>Security</option>
            <option>Balcony</option>
            <option>Tile Floor</option>
            <option>Dish Washer</option>
            <option>Dining Area</option>
            <option>Kitchen Cabinet</option>
            <option>Kitchen Shelf</option>
            <option>Wardrobe</option>
            <option>WIFI</option>
            <option>POP Ceiling</option>
            <option>Prepaid Meter</option>
            <option>Concrete Flooring</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Description</label>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" placeholder="Add more description to your Ad"
            id="description" cols="30" rows="30" style="height: 10rem;"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-b">Upload</button>
                  </div>`,
      landForm: `<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="file">Add Photo</label>
          <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple"
            class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="location">Location</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="location">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="title"
            placeholder="Title or name of the Land.">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="area">Property Size (sqm)</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="area">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="land-type">Type Of Land</label>
          <select class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="land-type" placeholder="What Type of Land is This?">
            <option>Commercial Land</option>
            <option>Farmland</option>
            <option>Industrial Land</option>
            <option>Mixed-use LAnd</option>
            <option>Quarry</option>
            <option>Residential Land</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="sale-status">For Sale Or Lease?</label>
              <select class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="sale-status">
                <option>For Sale</option>
                <option>For Lease</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="price">Price</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="price">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="amenities">Other Amenities</label>
          <select class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" id="amenities" multiple style="height: 10rem;">
            <option>Parking Space</option>
            <option>Electric Supply</option>
            <option>Domestic Sewage</option>
            <option>Gas Supply</option>
            <option>Rain Water Drainage</option>
            <option>Water Supply</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Description</label>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-a" placeholder="Add more description to your Ad"
            id="description" cols="30" rows="30" style="height: 10rem;"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-b">Upload</button>
                 </div>`
    },

    fromInputs: {
      Name: $('#title'),
      Brand: $('#brand'),
      Model: $('#car-model'),
      Location: $('#location'),
      Description: $('#description'),
      Status: $('#sale-status'),
      Price: $('#price'),
      Bedrooms: $('#bedrooms'),
      Bathrooms: $('#bathrooms'),
      Garage: $('#garage'),
      Area: $('#area'),
      Amenities: $('#amenities'),
      'Type Of Land': $('#land-type'),
      Year: $('#year'),
      Condition: $('#condition'),
      Transmission: $('#transmission'),
      Registered: $('#registered'),
      Mileage: $('#mileage'),
    },

    formImages: {
      dataReferenceId: 'dataid',
      images: []
    },

    dataToSubmit : ''
  };

  /*--/ Admin Page Code /--*/

  // Check what typemof data user wants to upload and display from related to that
  $('#upload').change(e => {

    switch (e.target.value) {
      case 'houses':
        $('.upload-type').text('Uploading A House');
        $('.form-upload').html(projectData.uploadCategories.houseForm);
        break;

      case 'land':
        $('.upload-type').text('Uploading A Land');
        $('.form-upload').html(projectData.uploadCategories.landForm);
        break;

      default:
        $('.upload-type').text('Uploading A Car');
        $('.form-upload').html(projectData.uploadCategories.carForm);
        break;
    }
  });


  // GET ALL UPLOAD FORM DATA INPUTED
  $('.form-upload').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Check what category user wants to upload
    const uploadCategory = $('#upload').val();

    // GET ALL THE DATA FOR A FORM SESSION UPLOADED
    const data = Object.entries(projectData.fromInputs).map(([key, value]) => [key, value && value.val()]);

    // FILTER THE DATA TO RETURN ON THOSE WITH VALUES 
     const filteredData = Object.fromEntries(
      data.filter(([key, value]) => value
    ));

    console.log(filteredData);
    // projectData.dataToSubmit = filteredData;

  });
```

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/genral-walker/pen/vYgqbvL

Comment: Please create [mcve]. Write the smallest possible version, ensure it's working and then expand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem is that you're caching reference to elements that might not be in DOM at the time. You should store a selector instead:

```
fromInputs: {
  Name: '#title',
  Brand: '#brand',
  Model: '#car-model',
  Location: '#location',
  Description: '#description',
  Status: '#sale-status',
  Price: '#price',
  Bedrooms: '#bedrooms',
  Bathrooms: '#bathrooms',
  Garage: '#garage',
  Area: '#area',
  Amenities: '#amenities',
  'Type Of Land': '#land-type',
  Year: '#year',
  Condition: '#condition',
  Transmission: '#transmission',
  Registered: '#registered',
  Mileage: '#mileage',
},
```

And then look it up later:

```
const data = Object.entries(projectData.fromInputs).map(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key, value);
  const $el = $(value);
  return [key, $el.length && $el.val()];
});
```

https://codepen.io/genral-walker/pen/vYgqbvL?editors=1111

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't think of this at all!